# what does return; mean?

Tags: c, function, prototype, return-type

The return data-type of a function,whose prototype is declared in main(), is void.
It cointains an instruction return; as in

```
main()
{
    void create(int *p);
    *some code*
}
void create(node *list)
{
     *some code*
     return;
}
```

What will it return,and where will it return??

Comment: A lot of functions in my firm's codebase have "return" as the last line of void functions. I was told "It's to tell the user we're ending the function". As if reaching the end of the function wasn't already enough?

Comment: does it mean that returning any integer is like ending a function,irrespctive of the value of hat integer?

Comment: @glowcoder: more interestingly, your colleagues seem to admit the user (other dev, I presume) has to read the code to know what it does.

Comment: @GrajeshBabu, yes whenever you have a return statement the execution of that function ends, no matter the value or the type of value.

Comment: @GrajeshBabu: dev = developer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not going to return anything, you might have return statements in a void function to kind of alter the flow and exit from the function. ie rather than:

```
void do_something(int i)
{
   if (i > 1) {
      /* do something */
   }
   /* otherwise do nothing */
}
```

you might have:

```
void do_something(int i)
{
   if (i <= 1)
      return;

   /* if haven't returned, do something */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case doesn't mean much.

return; means exit suddenly from this function returning void.

```
int a()
{
    return 10;
}

void b()
{
     return; // we have nothing to return, this is a void function.
}

void c()
{
    // we don't need return; it is optional.
}
```

return; for a void function is not useful, it can be omitted, is optional.
However sometime it is useful, for example, for exiting a loop or a switch.

```
void xxx()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        if (++i >= 100)
            return; // we exit from the function when we get 100.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`return;` won't return anything, which matches the declared `void` return type of the function `create`. It will return to the caller of the function it appears in (not shown in your example), just like `return EXPRESSION;` will.

In this particular piece of code, `return;` is redundant since it appears at the very end of `create`, but it's useful when you want to exit a function prematurely:

```
void print_error(char const *errmsg)
{
    if (errmsg == NULL)
        // nothing to print
        return;
    perror(errmsg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it will return from the executing function with a `void` return value (which means no value).